# Working with godaddy and third party and IIS DNS

Tags: dns

Hi I am hoping someone can help me with this question, as apparently the chat agent on godaddy couldn't.

I have a DNS for domain A registered with godaddy.

I have a number of sites running from my home pc which unfortunately uses dynamic IP, so I lose these sites everytime my ISP updates the IP address.

I have a no-ip service for Domain B which points directly to my home computer as is always maintained.   All of the sites I use with no-ip service are always pointing to the correct place.

Is there a way I can point my godaddy domains (Domain A) to my no-ip domain (Domain B) whilst keeping the original url?  I'm thinking its domain forwarding or something to do with NameServers, but this is an area in which I have zero knowledge.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This should instead be posted on serverfault.com instead of here

Comment: ok thanks, sorry didn't realise